# Apple Tax in iPhone shopping app?

Tags: ios, payment, credit-card

I'm about to implement credit card processing in a shoe shopping app for iPhone. I'm not using  in-app purchase.

**Will I have to pay 30% to Apple from the revenue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 30% fee is only if you use Apple's In-App Purchase API. If you are selling e-goods, then you are out of luck because you have to use the In-App API or else Apple will reject your App. One more thing, **you cannot use** IAP for non-electronic goods.

For anything other than electronic goods, you can use custom checkout and avoid the 30% fee. For example, you can use PayPal and pay a much smaller fee (~3% only, on average).

Finally, keep in mind that Apple will most certainly reject your App if you are managing sensitive user data yourself. For example, passing credit card numbers to your own backend server. At the very least, payment processing must be [PCI compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because Apple will not allow you to perform any in-app sales that do not run through *their* In-App Purchase APIs.